# How to check if domain exists

Tags: c#

We want to validate user’s email address in our website registration form by checking if email domain for entered email address exists. Is there a way to do this in C#.

More specifically – is there a way to retrieve website IP address by its domain in C#

Comment: yes, everything you are looking for is possible in C# and in the vast majority of programming Frameworks and API's.

Comment: Why don't you send a verification email with a verification link to the email. This is industry standard practice.

Comment: use : `Dns.GetHostAddresses`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is really two questions.

To answer the latter question first:

> More specifically – is there a way to retrieve website IP address by its domain in C#

Yes, perform a DNS lookup on the domain.

For example:

```
public static void DoGetHostEntry(string hostname)
{
    IPHostEntry host;

    host = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname);

    Console.WriteLine("GetHostEntry({0}) returns:", hostname);

    foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    {0}", ip);
    }
}
```

See MSDN for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998.aspx

Your second question is a little more complicated:

> We want to validate user’s email address in our website registration form by checking if email domain for entered email address exists. Is there a way to do this in C#.

It depends on what you mean by exist, the comment by @Jcl rightly points out it can be a little more nuanced depending on the DNS setup for that domain. It's perfectly possible for example for a domain to be registered and have no other records, it still exists even if it does nothing.

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles upon this, just note that "a hostname with the exact same name as the domain name can resolve to an IP address" is not the same as "a domain exists". A domain can be registered, and exist, and have subdomains, and have MX or other kind of DNS records but not an specific A record for "the domain name" without any subdomains, in which case, resolving the hostname of the domain name (without any subdomains) may give no results, and that doesn't mean the domain doesn't exist.

Comment: @Jcl Yes you're right, looking at it some years later it appears I really answered the latter question and not the former.

Comment: that was a great edit. Upvoted :-)